# Decrease execution time of the Java program

Tags: java, algorithm, primes, execution-time

I wrote the following program for the second problem of project Euler, for the question: "Project Euler #3: Largest prime factor".It is supposed to print out all the highest prime factors of the provided inputs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class euler_2 {
    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
        for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            for (int j = b; j >= 1; j--) {
                boolean aa = isPrime(j);
                if (aa == true && b % j == 0) {
                    b = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}
```

What changes can I make to the program to make it execute faster? What would be a better algorithm for this problem?

Comment: can you show us any attempt?

Comment: @Leo is his first attempt not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that for every number `N`, you try each number smaller or equal to `N` whether it is a prime and after that whether it is a divisor of `N`.

Obvious improvement is to check whether it is a divisor first and only then whether it is a prime. But most probably this will not help that much.

What you can do instead is just to start checking each number whether it is a divisor of a number. If it is a divisor, divide it. You continue this till `sqrt(N)`.

I have not done anything with java in a long time, but here is Go implementation, which most probably any Java person will be able to transform to Java.

```
func biggestPrime(n uint64) uint64 {
    p, i := uint64(1), uint64(0)
    for i = 2; i < uint64(math.Sqrt(float64(n))) + uint64(1); i++ {
        for n % i == 0 {
            n /= i
            p = i
        }
    }
    if n > 1 {
        p = n
    }
    return p
}
```

Using my algorithm it will take you O(sqrt(N)) to find the biggest prime of a number. In your case it was `O(N * sqrt(N))`

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to factor the number into 2 factors.  Repeat on the largest factor found so far until you find one that can't be factored -- that is the largest prime factor.

There are many different ways you might try to factor the numbers, but since they are only ints, then Fermat's method or even trial division (going down from sqrt(N)) will probably do.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsFactorizationMethod.html